# Create a new excel vs appending to existing one

Tags: c#, excel

I want to create an excel file for each day I run a Test, in D drive.

However, if the file already exists - as in I already ran a test for that day - I want it to append to the file.

This is what I got so far but I feel like it doesn't look right.

Any help would be great, Thanks a lot guys.

```
 Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
 string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd-yy");
 string myPath = @"D:\" + date + ".xls";
 int rowIndex = 1; int colIndex = 1;
 Excel._Workbook oWB;
 try
 {
            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath));

            excelApp.Visible = false;
            excelApp.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = "IN TRY METHOD";
            oWB.Save();
            oWB.Close();

  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(excelApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value));
            excelApp.Visible = false;
            excelApp.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = "IN CATCH METHOD";
            oWB.SaveAs(myPath);
            oWB.Close();
    }
```

Also I noticed that when I open the file it says:

> The file you are trying to open is in a different format than
>   specified by file extension. Verify it's from a trusted source before
>   opening the file. Do you want to open now?

It works but it has this message before hand.

So please tell me what I'm doing wrong and also how to make this code a lot cleaner.

Comment: You shouldn't really use try{}catch{} like that. You should really catch an exception and do something with the caught exception in the catch block.

Comment: Well, what does it do when you run it? You say "it doesn't look right", but what does it do? Just jump straight to your catch block after the first line in your Try?

And as @SamLeach said, you should try to catch a specific exception and do something about it instead of a broad catch-all like that.

Comment: Yeah thats what i meant by "doesn't look right". Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `try .. catch` this way you should first test to see if the file exists.  If it does, then do your append code.  If it doesn't then do the workbook creation code.

The reason you get that message is that you are using the newer Excel COM objects to create the file.  Instead of emitting `.xls` as the extension try `.xlsx`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the file is on disk and then take appropriate action instead of abusing `try{}catch{}`

```
if(File.Exists(myPath))
{
    ModifyExcel();
}
else
{
    CreateExcel();
}
```

---

```
private void ModifyExcel()
{
    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath));
    excelApp.Visible = false;
    excelApp.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = "MODIFY";
    oWB.Save();
    oWB.Close();
}

private void CreateExcel()
{
    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(excelApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value));
    excelApp.Visible = false;
    excelApp.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = "CREATE";
    oWB.SaveAs(myPath);
    oWB.Close();
}
```

Comment: Right when i was going to post that i should use File.Exists you beat me to it. lol Thanks a lot!!

Comment: +1: better answer than mine (you actually included code).  Just add the part about the xlsx and your gold.